# sin(pi()) does not return 0 in DDMathParser

Tags: objective-c, ddmathparser

I'm making a calculator app using DDMathParser. The problem I'm facing is `sin(pi())` doesn't return 0 but a trivial number like 1.2246...e-16. I'm just wondering is there any way to convert it to 0?
Thank you.

Comment: No need for DDMathParser for that. Just use `sin(M_PI);`.

Comment: I'd like to convert any input expressions into a double value, so it's by far easier to write if I use a math parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-description` method on `NSNumber` does not accurately represent the underlying number:

```
NSLog(@"%f", sin(M_PI));    // logs 0.000000
NSLog(@"%@", @(sin(M_PI))); // logs 1.224646799147353e-16
```

To work around this, you can pull out the `-doubleValue` of the `NSNumber`, and that should give you `0`:

```
NSLog(@"%f", @(sin(M_PI)).doubleValue); // logs 0.000000
```

Comment: You are cheating here: `M_PI` is not exactly π, and therefore `sin(M_PI)` is not exactly zero. `NSLog(@"%f", sin(M_PI))` logs 0.000000 because it rounds to a precision of 6 decimal digits, not because it is "more accurate" than the description method of NSNumber.